# Magento 2: How to pass object as a argument from phtml

Tags: magento2, phtml, object

I want to pass object as a argument from phtml file how can I do this? As I've checked we can pass string using `$block->setData('var','test')` but didn't found for object.

Comment: May I know how you write block file?

Comment: I've created block using $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('') in phtml and want to  pass object as a argument on that block.

Answer (score 0):

> a simple example to pass a variable from Magento (template,
>   controller, etc) file to a block with php code.
>
> Call a block using the createBlock() method:

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/template_name')
->setData('key', $obj)
->setTemplate('module/newblock.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Comment: Using above code we can pass xsi:type="string" argument and I want to pass xsi:type="object" argument which is not possible with above solution.

Comment: you can fetch object like this $block->getData('key') in your phtml

Comment: I want to pass argument using set method. I don't want to get anything.

Comment: but some where you used this object am I right?

Comment: Any solution for this ? I want to pass object as a argument

Answer (score 0):

Even if this post is 3 years old I'll answer it in case someone needs the solution.

WARNING: you should never use `getLayout()->createBlock`, the correct way would be creating a new `<block>` inside the layout.xml. Also, you should never use ObjectManager as done in this answer, but it's the only way that I found working with the `getLayout()->createBlock` instruction.

This is the solution (inside your .phtml):

```
<?php

// Get an instance of the class to pass to the block as argument
$obj = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->get(ObjectClassToPassToBlock::class);

...

// Create the block passing it the object inside the param "argumentKey"
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    Block::class,
    'block_name',
    [
        'data' => ['argumentKey' => $obj]
    ]
);
?>
<?= $block->toHtml(); ?>

...
```

Doing like this you will create a block with name `block_name` and class `Block::class` and you will pass it an argument of type `xsi:type="object"` inside `argumentKey`

If you want to set the arguments of the block using the `$block->setData` instruction you can do like this:

```
$block->setData('argumentKey', $obj);
```